# Is there a way to get notified when a comment is posted

Tags: website

Is there a site that will notify me when someone responds to a comment on another site like on reddit or stackoverflow? I get tired of the refresh, wait, refresh cycle.

Comment: There are ways, but they're likely to be different for every site or blog platform.

Comment: This is quite vague please more specific about which website.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Check4Change](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/3028/) plugin for FireFox

> Check4Change (aka C4C) is a simple
>   extension that allows you to
>   periodically check a web-page for
>   updates.
>
> Have you ever found yourself pressing
>   the reload button frantically, waiting
>   for something in the web page to
>   change? Well reload no further! with
>   C4C you'll just mark the relevant
>   text, set a time interval (e.g. every
>   1 minute), and you're done!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most sites have the option of sending an email when another user coments, it depends on the website, for example in quora you can go to settings->Email Settings ->question Related-> and check the boxes of when you want an email to be sent to you (for example when Someone answers a question I'm following), and you can recieve emails in many other cases that this application allows. You can also get notified when events from questions answered by you happen, by checking the desired checkbox from in which case you wanna be notified.

In the stackoverflow website when you ask a new question you have a checkbox at the bottom of it, that if you check it, it will enable to recieve emails to notify you that there was a new answer to your question.

Each site depends.